# Prove that $n! = \Omega(n^{100})$

Tags: sorting

I justed started studying the sorting algorithm, so I need help solving problems on (big Omega) $\Omega$

How can I Prove that $n! = \Omega(n^{100})$

I know that we write $f(x) = \Omega(g(x))$ if $g(x) = O(f(x))$. This means that there is a constant $c>0$ and a value $x_0$ such that $|f(X)| \ge cg(x)$ whenever $x>x_0$.

Hence from the definition above, I can write
$$n^{100} = O(n!)$$

We can find a constant c and a value $x_0$ such that $n^{100} \le O(n!)$ for all $x>x_0$.
We could take $c=1$ and $x_0=1$

I don't know if I am correct. Please how should I continue and complete the proof.

Comment: Hint: take $x_0 = 100$ and $c = 100^{100}$.

Comment: $n^{100} \in \mathcal O(n!)$ iff $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^{100}}{n!} < \infty$ and the latter is obvious (the limit is zero, so it's in fact little-o of $n! $)